# Is it possible to use a variable as an operator?

Tags: notation

This is more of a notation question, but is there a (correct) way to use an operator as a variable? Like this perhaps$$\text{let H be} <$$ or
$$H:<$$
Where $H$ is now equivalent to $<$

Comment: Technically the concept of a variable operator is present in mathematical logic, abstract algebra, and computer programming. But in more commonplace, applied mathematics? Not so much.

Comment: Often times equivalence relations are denoted by a letter such as $R$. You may write $aRb$ to say that $a$ is equivalent to $b$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing in mathematics says that letters represent "variables". All you are doing here is using a different symbol for the standard inequality symbol (which is not an "operator").

Redefining $<$ as $H$ would be legal but very confusing.

In some computer languages ([lisp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_(programming_language)#Operators) is one) you can specify operators as variables. For example, you might define a function this way:

```
f( a, b, op) 
   return a op b
```

Then

$f(3,4,+) = 7$ while $f(3,4,\times) = 12$.